# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown Even the driver is checking for null before quitting

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have code like below...

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup() throws InterruptedException {
    driver = DriverFactory.getDriverInstance();
    softwarepage = new SoftwarePage(driver);
    loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
    projectpage = new ProjectPage(driver);
}

@Test(description="Create Software",dataProviderClass=AddSoftwareProvider.class,dataProvider="testCasesAddSoftware")
public void createSoftware(AddSoftwareBean softwareBean) throws InterruptedException
{
    softwareName = "AutoSoftware"+DataGenerator.randomNumber();
    log.info("Create Software test case Started...");
    assertEquals(true, loginpage.gotoSignPage());
    assertEquals(true,loginpage.logintoPortal(PropertyMap.getInstance().getmySSISSGName(), PropertyMap.getInstance().getmySSISSGPassword(), "myToday"));
    //assertEquals(true,softwarepage.createSoftware(softwareName));
    //assertEquals(true,softwarepage.AddSoftwareDefault(softwareName, "Low"));
    assertEquals(true,softwarepage.AddSoftware(softwareBean));

}
```

I am quitting the driver in teardown method like below, but before checking whether the driver is null or not... Even, then the above test case is not executing...

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        assertEquals(true,loginpage.logout());
        driver.quit();
        }
}
```

in the softwarePage, the code is like this...

```
public SoftwarePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
@Override
protected WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

Please help me in this...

Edit:

The full stack is here... The assertion is in logout method I have written...

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [false[ but found ]true]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:286)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:296)
    at com.cigital.myssi.automation.commons.Verification.assertEquals(Verification.java:33)
    at com.cigital.myssi.automation.tests.SoftwareTest.tearDown(SoftwareTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:225)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

EDIT: without assertion in tearDown method, this is what I am getting...

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Comment: Aren't `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotated methods supposed to be static?  http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html  http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html  Also, what exception are you getting?

Comment: I am using testng framework...  FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown

Comment: Can you add the full stack to the question?

Comment: The assert is failing `assertEquals(true,loginpage.logout());`  Also you have expected and actual switched.  http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals(boolean, boolean)

Comment: If i have removed the assertion line in tearDown, then the browser opens and closes down...

Comment: `loginpage.logout()` is returning false.

Comment: If I have removed that assertion, It opens and quits, it should at least consider the above @Test annotation... Everything is worked fine for before 30 minutes, but this problem came after that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98924/discussion-between-lokesh-s-and-taylor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I found my mistake after debugging. The error lied in my CSVReader file which it reads data from the 2nd line after the heading. It prone the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to assert values on teardown :

```
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        loginpage.logout()); //You might want to debug this though
        driver.quit();
        }
}
```

**edit** : I would have preferred to use `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` for your Test && `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` for the entire Test Suite instead of `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`

Comment: If I have removed that assertion, It opens and quits, it should at least consider the above @Test annotation... Everything is worked fine for before 30 minutes, but this problem came after that.

Comment: You can see the stack trace without assertion

Comment: @LokeshS updated the answer and could you ensure the flow of your tests execution doesn't include any other methods in between?

Answer (score 0):

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
          try {
              assertEquals(true,loginpage.logout()); 
          } finally {
              driver.quit(); 
          }
        }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From exception it appears that it fails here:

```
at com.cigital.myssi.automation.commons.Verification.assertEquals(Verification.java:33)
at com.cigital.myssi.automation.tests.SoftwareTest.tearDown(SoftwareTest.java:69)
```

So what is that code? I assume it overrides `assertEquals` in some way, and maybe not in a way that is compatible with boolean.
In any case, you could use `assertTrue`, i.e.:

```
assertTrue(loginpage.logout());
```

Comment: Forget about logout method, If I have removed that line... It is not executing test in the @Test annotation...